# Why does Windows XP in best performance mode shows wrong icon for a split second?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, windows-xp, icons

In the last version of our software we changed the icon used everywhere in the application.
This because the corporate identity changed and the old green icon needed to change to the new red icon.

What I did to change it:

- Use the new icon in the Application settings of the startup project.
- Use the new icon on all the forms (only changed 1 form because all others inherit from this one).

Everything works perfect accept for Windows XP in Best Performance mode (right click Computer, Properties, Advanced, Presentation settings).

When starting the application it shows the Login screen in the taskbar with the old icon which changes in the new icon within a split second. Of course; the slower the machine, the longer the old icon is visible.

Seems to me it has something to do with caching of the old icon.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Searching for `shell icon cache xp` seems to produce a fair few hits with suggestions.

Comment: Also, it probably implies that you've left some versioning information untouched between the old and new version, so that XP believes that the cached icon is still valid.

Comment: There is a copy of your old icon on the system.  You will have to locate this, unless the icon goes back after it changes, I don't se the problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the hints, it pointed me the right way. I changed the name of the icon and the problem is solved.

Comment: You probably ought to change the versioning information - and get into the habit of doing so. You'll fall into pits later (possibly) if an older and newer version of the same piece of software present the same version information to the OS.